# Stick element to bottom side

Tags: css, sticky-footer

on my shop I have a green bar that I would like to **stick to the bottom side** (and the pink bar underneath it would be set to display:none)

http://www.screencast.com/t/v0IG2rWNlb

Example of product page on which it appears (site is responsive so you can mimic mobile view with playing with the frame of your window)
https://www.tresor-ethnique.com/collections/tibetain/products/pendentif-arbre-de-vie

I have tried :

```
.prod_form.prod_form_footer.sticky_addcart #AddToCart {
    bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

This green bar won't stick to the bottom side ....

You have any idea?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: You need to give it position: fixed

Answer (score 0):

Hey Pascal i looked into your url and here is your problem set the display property of pink to hidden and there is a parent to your green element which has the property of top: 0!important; remove that and you are good to go.

Comment: I have applied for just mobile and it worked! (conflict with parent indeed)
thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.pink-bar{ display: none; }
.green-bar{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0
}
```

This CSS may help you. as this will hide your pink bar and fixed the green bar to bottom

Comment: I have applied for just mobile and it worked! (conflict with parent indeed)
thank you :)